# UVW Unwrap multiple quads on same texture space automatically

Tags: 3d, 3dsmax, uv-mapping

I've been looking around the web for the answer to this question, but to no avail. So here I go.

I'm looking for a way to automatically map several quads on the same texture space (for example (0,0) ~ (0.4,0.4)) using the UVW unwrapper modifier of Max (or something else).

Here is a quick (and dirty) graphical explanation (click for larger): [image: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/14258744/maxuv.jpg]

Answer (score 2):

In the edit UV's we have flatten mapping, make sure you check down all the three boxes and click ok. This will adjust your UV's automatically in the texture space.

But from your image, it seems like you are texturing a track or road something like that. If in that case, i suggest you to follow this tutorial. Explains how to texture road/race track using tilable texture.

http://3dlad.com/how-to-texture-unwrap-a-race-track/